# ToolStrip TextBox Colour

Tags: c#, colors, textbox, toolstrip

I have set up a ToolStrip in my C# WinForms project and have added a TextBox on it.  I'm just curious whether it is normal that the TextBox is barely visible due to the colour of the ToolStrip and TextBox.

I could put a border around it or change the background colour of the TextBox but that just looks odd.

Is there some property which I haven't thought of which I could set to make it stand out more but not look out of place?

Screenshot added:

[image: textbox]

Comment: can you add even a little screenshot of what your textbox looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very light border would probably be best.  if you use the same color as the toolstrip, you won't really notice the border at the bottom, but it will make the top of the search box stand out.  you might also want to add a margin around it, or less padding inside of it, so it doesn't fill up the whole hight.